# Is this React ? How can I find out from the files? It looks very similar to Angular

Tags: reactjs, filetree

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKmnE.png)

```
.
├── assets
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   └── application.js
│   └── sass
│       └── application.scss
├── config.json
├── data
│   └── session-data-defaults.js
├── filters.js
├── routes.js
└── views
    ├── index.html
    └── layouts
        └── main.html

6 directories, 8 files
```

Searched the documentation. Asked on Reddit.
How can I find out if this is react or react based. It looks very similar to Angular ?
Thank You.

Comment: By reading what's in the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for a ReactDOM.render() method or even for JSX syntax in the code..